# Why can't I install ubuntu on my computer?

Tags: installation

I have a new MSI GT70 with windows 8, which has the new UEFI settings, and it just won't install ubuntu 12.10. I have tried a lot of different options to try and install it. I have tried using `nomodeset` and `acpi=off`,but everything has failed. I have even tried going into the bios and turning off `fast boot`, `secure boot`, and switched it over to `legacy mode`. All have got me somewhere in the installation, but it will not actually install ubuntu. By the way I have been using a CD.

At first when I just tried to install ubuntu without any special stuff from the bios, a screen with four options would appear. The top option was `try ubuntu without installing`, then `install ubuntu`, then `OEM`, and finally `check disc for defects`. Any option I hit enter on would cause my computer to just go to a black screen.

Next I tried to switch the bios settings to turning off `fast boot`, `secure boot`, and switching it to `legacy mode`. After I did this, I got the furthest with the installation, but it still failed. What happened was, it brought up a new ubuntu menu where six items appeared. They were the same as before with two additional ones that said `boot from first hard drive` and something else I cannot remember.If I entered into any of these options, it would display a bunch of code in like a command prompt, but then at the end, it would go to a black screen yet again.

My computer has two internal drives on it, one 128gb SSD and another 750gb HDD.
Let me know if you need anymore info. I really need to install ubuntu for school. Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: I have already done everything that tutorial has said and still no correct installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use amd64 version of ubuntu. You can get it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
From the same link:

```
Have a new PC with the Windows 8 logo or using UEFI firmware?
Please use a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu desktop.
```

Full reason [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for it to only work with the 64bit version.

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows 8 and using a 64 bit ubuntu disc